# I can't install my APK: parsing the package fails

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

So I finished making my test APK what I made in Android Studio and tried to install the app on my phone I get an error: "there was a problem in parsing the package" I have even tried just normally building APK and also I tried unsigned/signed APK and still not working. Here is all the code I used to make the app:

Also I used this tutorial: https://youtu.be/92f4c2vHrPg?list=FL-enUuEaX-zrgjvaCOrqRSQ

```
package com.example.sami.kartta;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(60.167469, 24.930913)).title("Helsinki"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }


<resources>
<!--
TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=5A:5C:C8:D8:90:F8:81:95:79:34:0B:C7:08:57:6A:32:71:72:26:68%3Bcom.example.sami.kartta

You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using these values:

Package name:
5A:5C:C8:D8:90:F8:81:95:79:34:0B:C7:08:57:6A:32:71:72:26:68

SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
5A:5C:C8:D8:90:F8:81:95:79:34:0B:C7:08:57:6A:32:71:72:26:68

Alternatively, follow the directions here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">YOUR_KEY_HERE</string>
AIza(Censored)
```

```
    package com.example.sami.kartta;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Example local unit test, which will execute on the development machine (host).
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }
}




    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sami.kartta">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application>
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Karttajuttu"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="7571000" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you installing through Android Studio, or generating an APK, copying it to the device, and trying to install it there?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions that Google suggests when googling for "there was a problem in parsing the package"?

Comment: Yes I made the app with Android Studio same way as shown in the Youtube video in my post. And I only tried to find other ways to build the APK.